# List all fields with search criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table where titles are randomly distributed over columns and rows.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | title | A |  |  |
| title | B |  | title | C |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | title | D |  |

In a second sheet I want to list all the titles like this:

|  |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

The order does not matter, but it should be referenced.

I have tried with `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` as well as `LOOKUP()`. It seems like I'd have to use an array function, but it doesn't work for me yet. One issue is, that `MATCH()` does not allow searching over the entire table.

Example of what I tried:

```
{=INDEX(Table1!1:1000;LARGE((Table1!A:E=„title“);COUNTIF(Table1!A:E;“title“)+ROW(TABLE2!A2)))}
```

Another approach was using `MATCH()`:

```
{=INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$E$100;MATCH("title";Table1!$E$1:$E$100;0);MATCH("title";Table1!$A$16:$J$16;0)+1)}
```

The issues with the later version are:

1. I only get 1 of the titles
2. I have to specifically call for each row (16) and column (E), instead of getting an automatic search. I would like to sear all columns and rows.

Comment: Please clarify the question a bit more. How is the formula (or us) expected to know which cells in the table are titles? Is it that each title has the word 'title' next to it?

Comment: I agree that an array function will be necessary - what do you mean by 'doesn't work for me yet'? Could you post what you've tried or what error messages you're getting?

Comment: Yes, each title has title in the cell to the left of it. So my approach was to find all fields with „title“ in it and then add 1 the the collumn index.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: @Harun24HR 2016

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=FILTERXML("<b><a>" & TEXTJOIN("</a><a>", TRUE, IF(A1:E3="Title", OFFSET(A1:E3, 0, 1), "")) & "</a></b>", "//a")
```

as an Array formula, where `A1:E3` is range to be filtered.

EDIT just seen you're using Excel 2016, not 100% sure that'll work for you but give it a try